# Compiling letter using xelatex and Sublime Text 3?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, sublime-text

I recently upgraded to Sublime Text 3. I have troubles compiling a letter template that requires the fontspec package and compilation with xelatex. I'm using the LaTeXTools package and tell Sublime to use the xelatex by the following line in the .tex-file: %!TEX program =

I'm using MacTex 2014 and have all packages and updates installed via TexLive Utility. When trying to compile my file, I get the an error message related to the fontspec package. When checking the log-file, I found out that LaTeXTools is trying to use pdflatex and not xelatex.

The weird thing is, that exactly the same configuration works fine with Sublime Text 2. Does my configuration simply not work in Sublime 3 or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a MWE that shows the problem. :)